# How to control whether the initd script or the systemd unit file is used to start/stop/control the service?

Tags: services, systemd, init.d, init

Some packages, like `apt-cacher-ng` provide both a `/etc/init.d/apt-cacher-ng` and `/lib/systemd/system/apt-cacher-ng.service`. That might be a good or bad idea (in comparison to providing an `apt-cacher-ng-initd` and `apt-cacher-ng-systemd` package). Since `systemd` can use `initd` script to start/stop/otherwise control service through `service`. Which file takes precedence? How to disable and enable one or the other?

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.